# Android app for Wifi automation

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an android app that triggers Wifi..

When we open the app, if our Wifi is on, it will toast Connected Message
 Else, a button having a text connect will be displayed and
when you click that button, button text will change to connected and your Wifi is turned on.

I have done this .. but 
my sir asked me to introduce such change that once we press button it changes from connect to connected and Wifi is on..

Now, if we manually turn off the Wifi in our setting and then we open our paused app, then the button will show connect option again.

I want to introduce automation in my app. My sir gave me hint that there is some **helper class in android which keep on calling the method** or **some event handler that handles the event that occurs outside the app**, but I still have no idea how to do that.

Please help me, thanks!

Here is the java code of my app:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    WifiManager wf;
    static Button buttn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttn.setOnClickListener(this);
        wf = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttn) {
            wf.setWifiEnabled(true);
            buttn.setText("connected");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at an Activity's Life cycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

I believe you'll be interested in the "onResume" and able to detect if WiFi is still connected there.

Comment: Thank you Greg but I have done this using broadcast receiver.

Comment: Awesome, glad you found something that worked. On that note, knowing the activity life cycle is almost required when making any application, so knowing that diagram would help you immensely in the future. Happy coding!

Comment: Can you  help me. I want to implement the Raised Button in android for API lower than 21 and It should work as normal button(but should be Raised Button) in API below 21 But show the ripple effect if we run the app on API 21 or onward. @Greg

Comment: @PrakharSharma This question is completely unrelated to the original question, so asking in the comments field adds nothing to this post. If I recall, this relates to a design spec and not an actual button... Please make a new post with the new question.